# Can we find out which mesh a point belongs to in FiPy by searching with the coordinate?

Tags: fipy

I have two meshes defined in FiPY as follows:

```
gmsh_mesh = fp.Gmsh2D("ProcessSim_CMOS_Step1.msh")

from fipy.meshes.mesh2D import Mesh2D

def extract_mesh(mesh, mask):
    cellFaceIDs = mesh.cellFaceIDs[..., mask]
    faceIDs = numerix.unique(cellFaceIDs.flatten())
    facemap = numerix.zeros(mesh.faceVertexIDs.shape[1], dtype=int)
    facemap[faceIDs] = faceIDs.argsort()
    
    faceVertexIDs = mesh.faceVertexIDs[..., faceIDs]
    vertIDs = numerix.unique(faceVertexIDs.flatten())
    vertmap = numerix.zeros(mesh.vertexCoords.shape[1], dtype=int)
    vertmap[vertIDs] = vertIDs.argsort()

    return Mesh2D(mesh.vertexCoords[..., vertIDs],
                  vertmap[faceVertexIDs],
                  facemap[cellFaceIDs])

oxideMesh = extract_mesh(mesh=gmsh_mesh, mask=gmsh_mesh.physicalCells["Oxide"])
siliconMesh = extract_mesh(mesh=gmsh_mesh, mask=gmsh_mesh.physicalCells["Silicon"])
```

So while doing process simulation, say etching, the user wants to selectively etch the specified material. To assign different etch rate to different points, I want to find whether a coordinate <x, y, 0.0> belongs to oxideMesh or siliconMesh. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FiPy doesn't provide any capability like this and isn't likely to. If your
meshes were simply connected and convex, then you could use
[`scipy.spatial.tsearch`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.tsearch.html%5D) with the mesh vertices.
Unfortunately, based on your [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68734234/can-you-create-separate-meshes-in-fipy-by-reading-physical-names-from-gmsh) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68596013/fipy-how-to-find-node-vertex-at-interface-between-two-mesh), this approach
won't work for you.

Many years ago, I did some work with semiconductor heterostructures, where
I needed to account for different domain geometries built up during successive lithographic and electrodeposition steps. I used the
[Shapely](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/) package to define abstract geometrical domains and then
converted those domains to a FiPy mesh with Gmsh. Shapely can be used to
check point containment, even when the domains are concave or disconnected. The specifics were a bit different from what you're doing, but I believe it's still applicable.

This [gist](https://gist.github.com/guyer/23a1aee71e3120258c91d3bdc42f8a00) illustrates building multiple complex domains, checking
point containment in them, and then generating a single FiPy mesh from
them (which was my use-case; you could generate separate meshes from
separate domains).

[image: Shapely geometry of pn junction]
[image: FiPy meshing of Shapely geometry]

```py
In [5]:
pt = Point((-5e-7, 3.99e-7))
ntype.contains(pt), ptype.contains(pt)
Out[5]:
(True, False)
In [6]:
pt = Point((-5e-7, 4e-7))
ntype.contains(pt), ptype.contains(pt)
Out[6]:
(False, False)
In [7]:
pt = Point((-5e-7, 4.01e-7))
ntype.contains(pt), ptype.contains(pt)
Out[7]:
(False, True)
In [8]:
pt = Point((-5e-7, 4.0e-7))
ntype.touches(pt), ptype.touches(pt)
Out[8]:
(True, True)
```

Comment: I think I found a way to work this out with shapely looking at your `gist` script. Thanks!